Quill Editor cursor positions itself behind the first letter
This is not a question, but something I just ran into using the Quill editor, and thought I would share just in case anyone else runs into the same problem.
if you have encountered, when typing, the cursor positions itself behind the first letter, I have a fix - in jquery.
$('.quill').each((i, q) => {
  new Quill(q, {
    modules: {
  toolbar: toolbarOptions
},
theme: 'snow',
placeholder: 'Type here...',
  });  
}).on('focus', (e) => {
  $(this).text($(this).text().substring($(this).text().length, -1));// this is what does it
});

I'm sure you can adapt it to React, Angular or Vue

If this is supposted to be a self-answered question, please note it must still be a separate, high quality question ([ask]) and answer ([answer]).

Also I am unbale to reproduce the issue here: https://quilljs.com/playground/snow

I came across the same issue and I found what the problem was.
.ql-editor > * { 
  cursor: text;
}

This is the default css style of quill, I just changed it to my custom code:
.ql-editor > * { 
  cursor: initial !important;
}

The cursor started working normal again, hope this helps :)
